# Adding a space between two separate string variables in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the username and password to print out on the same line, but have a space in between the two variables. Extra context with what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to create a password/username (encryption?) or privacy setting you could call it. (User inputs name and password then is prompted with random numbers, symbols, or letters to hide information.

```
Console.WriteLine(userName + passWord); // (usernamepassword) is the current output.
```

I'm obviously new to C# and appreciate any and all help. I couldn't find an answer on google or the forum.

Comment: you can simply do userName + " " + passWord

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Agreed.

Answer (score 5):

I need to cover this first before getting into the actual answer:

It's **never** okay to keep a password in a recoverable format. Even encryption is *not good enough*, because it implies the potential for decryption. If you're handling passwords properly, they are stored using a [*one-way hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), such that whenever someone tries to login you re-hash the attempted password and only compare the hashes. Anything else is asking for big trouble.

Don't write passwords back to the screen for confirmation, and don't write them into log files.

---

That out of the way, you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{userName} {passWord}");
```

or this

```
Console.WriteLine(userName + " " + passWord);
```

or this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", userName, passWord);
```

Comment: yup, don't output the password

Comment: option 1: string interpolation

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this is simply a fun thing to do in my opinion. Outputting back to the console window is just to appreciate the accomplishment on my end. Having fun here while learning, not to be taken seriously.

Comment: @HaydenBrah I understand. But it's important to start using good habits early. Also, one of the purposes for Stack Overflow is to leave good artifacts behind for others (usually via Google).  Answering this question with no discussion of password handling would create a bad artifact.

Comment: You're very right, not a good idea to throw "good habits" out the window. I was thinking selfishly and not thinking about someone needing the answer to this exact question in the future. Thank you, thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to do this many times (say, put spaces between each of 50 variables), you will want to use a `StringBuilder` (calling the `Append` or `AppendLine` methods).  Many string concatenations is generally a code-smell.  In this case, @JoelCoehoorn's examples are the things to use

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine can take a format string and parameters so you can easily build it like so

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", userName, passWord);
```

Another option is to use String interpolation.  This is new syntax in C#6 that is essentially the same as above

```
Console.WriteLine($"{userName} {passWord}");
```

Answer (score 0):

userName and password are just strings. A + just concatenates strings together, so you can simply concatenate another string with a space in it between them:

```
Console.WriteLine(userName + " " + passWord);
```